# Azure Site Recovery with Traffic Manager

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager, azure-site-recovery

I have setup 3 VMs (all based in Azure) in a "Site Recovery Plan" and the test failover of these works correctly.

However, I wish to front these VMs with a "Traffic Manager" such that on failover the traffic is routed to the failed over VM in the target region.

I have followed the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/concepts-traffic-manager-with-site-recovery#azure-to-azure-failover

As the source VM exists I can select it as an "Azure Endpoint" in the "Traffic Manager" profile. But as the target endpoint doesn't exist until after failover, the guide says to select it as an "External Endpoint".

However, what value should I put for FQDN or IP?

The only information I have pre-failover is the internal static IP which it will be assigned (it does not have a DNS label or Public IP as ASR cannot provide this on failover), but this cannot be used in a "Traffic Manager" profile which contains an "Azure Endpoint".

Is there a better way to automate the routing of the traffic to the failover VM post-failover?

Answer (score 0):

> However, what value should I put for FQDN or IP?

Perhaps, you can put a public-facing [standard load balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-overview) in front of the VMs, then use the static public IP address of load balancer in a "Traffic Manager" profile.

For more details, you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/networking/disaster-recovery-dns-traffic-manager#automatic-failover-using-azure-traffic-manager).

### Update

You can use an ASR recovery plan and Azure Automation runbooks to assign static public IPs to a VM following a test failover.

For more info, refer to [add Azure Automation runbooks to recovery plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-runbook-automation)

and  [Add Public IP and NSG to ARM VMs during Test Failover of an ASR Recovery Plan](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Add-Public-IP-and-NSG-to-a6bb8fee)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however this will not work in my case. The reason being that as I am using Azure Site Recovery, the VMs for the failover region do not exist until after failover. Therefore, I cannot assign a load balancer to them...

Comment: @JamesElder  Update my reply.